# Symfony: Disable environment variables from caching

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I am running a Symfony 2.8.6 application on nginx/php-fpm.

There are multiple domains that are resolved into this server, and basically what I want to do is change RDB configuration according to which domain was used to access.

So my nginx.conf has lines like `fastcgi_param SYMFONY__SOME__PARAM $host`, but I have a problem.
This parameter injection is cached and not working as intended.

For example, there are two domains `a.example.com` and `b.example.com`, and they point to my server.
I want it to connect to different MySQL server when accessed through different domain, but it ignores the domain and connects to the same server always.

What I've confirmed:

- Nginx passes the variable correctly.
- The output of `var_dump($_SERVER['SYMFONY__SOME__PARAM'])` changes as expected.
- The parameter is stored in `app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php`

AFAIS there are two options: disabling configuration cache totally, or disabling caching environment variables.
I think the latter option is more preferrable, but I even don't know how to disable the cache, whether totally or partially.

Answer (score 1):

Using dynamic environment variables in service definitions is not possible in Symfony (see [symfony/symfony#16403 (comment)](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/16403#issuecomment-156015119) why). You can try to use [Incenteev/DynamicParametersBundle](https://github.com/Incenteev/DynamicParametersBundle), but I have no experience with it.

Comment: Thanks! I tried Incenteev/DynamicParametersBundle and [fervo/EnvironmentBundle](https://github.com/fervo/EnvironmentBundle), but both seem to have the same problem (parameters are cached). Currently what I did is overriding `initializeContainer` in `AppKernel.php` so that environment parameters are refreshed every time, and that hack actually worked, but I want to know if there are better ways.

Comment: And what did you do in `initializeContainer`? Disable the cache in production is not a good idea. I think DynamicParametersBundle should work but it has some limitations you have to keep in mind (but the usage example seems to do what you need)... "Getting a parameter from the container directly at runtime will not use the environment variable" (you have to use `$this->get('incenteev_dynamic_parameters.retriever')->get('param')`) , "Parameters or arguments built by concatenating other parameters together will not rely on the environment variables"

Comment: DynamicParametersBundle is not what I want because of the second limitation you pointed out (and written in readme). It can't be used for DBAL configuration.What I did was just overriding `getDefaultParameters` of ProjectContainer (a cached class) so that it will read the _current_ environment variables.

Comment: No, it didn't work, but I found another way: overriding `getContainerClass`.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing cache directory for each environemnt.

```
fastcgi_param SYMFONY__CACHE_DIR /path/to/cache
```